# Как убрать GOPROXY при сборке пакета

Tags: linux, golang

У меня возникла такая проблема: я хочу собрать у себя на локальной машине без интернета библиотеку `msgpack` для *Go.* При сборке он говорит что не может перейти по ссылке через `GOPROXY`. Если затереть путь `GOPROXY`, он будет говорить что `GOPROXY` выключен, и пройти невозможно.

Я знаю что есть другие пути решения этой проблемы, но мне бы хотелось именно узнать как можно сделать так что бы при сборке он шел не через `GOPROXY`, а искал данные в `GOROOT` или ещё где.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте установить переменную `GOPRIVATE`:

> ```
> The GOPRIVATE environment variable controls which modules the go command
> considers to be private (not available publicly) and should therefore not use the
> proxy or checksum database. The variable is a comma-separated list of
> glob patterns (in the syntax of Go's path.Match) of module path prefixes.
> For example,
>
>     GOPRIVATE=*.corp.example.com,rsc.io/private
>
> causes the go command to treat as private any module with a path prefix
> matching either pattern, including git.corp.example.com/xyzzy, rsc.io/private,
> and rsc.io/private/quux.
> ```

То есть, если ваши приватные модули находятся в пространстве
`example.com`, то вам надо проставить:

```sh
$ export GOPRIVATE="example.com"
```

Подробнее см. документацию `go help module-private`:

```sh
$ go help module-private
```